# Terminator with two or more open tabs leave the window with a white border on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, terminator, borders

I'm using Lubuntu 17.10, and I installed Terminator. When opening two tabs, I noticed that the window, even in full screen, has an ugly white border around all of it.

[image]

Seeing the image here might be difficult because of the white background, but this is the image of a full screen Terminator with two tabs opened. How can I get rid of it? Is it LXDE's fault?

Answer (score 3):

I opened [gtk-inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) from terminal, I couldn't open it from terminator itself.
Using the gtk-inspector I found the following css rule added to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` removed the ugly white border.

```
.terminator-terminal-window notebook header, .terminator-terminal-window stack {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: It did not work for Ubuntu 18

Comment: That works in Manjaro with Gnome!

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me. Use the following in your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
.terminator-terminal-window notebook {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, try at least telling op where to put these lines

Comment: That is exactly what I did and it works like a charm.

Comment: Great, that worked! I restarted Gnome Shell with Alt+F2, r (maybe it was not needed). And restarted `terminator`. I had gtk-4.0 directory as well, but gtk-3.0 worked fine. Note that if you want to add comments in CSS, use /* */.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably gtk theme's fault. I has this border with arc-gtk-theme, but not with some others

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04

I also used the gtk-inspector to find this.
Note : I started terminator with gnome-terminal using : `GTK_DEBUG=interactive terminator`. It doesn't work with other terminal. (you also need to activate gtk-inspector before that with

Here's my gtk.css configuration to fix this :

```
    .terminator-terminal-window notebook tab {
         margin-left: 0px;
         margin-right: 0px;
    }


    .terminator-terminal-window notebook tabs {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
```

I've added a couple of fancy things that I like. So there's my full gtk.css

```
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    min-height:0;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tabs {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked {
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffde33;
    background-color: #330;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: #550;
}
.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab button{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab button:hover{
    background-color: #550;
}
```